# UI form dynamicrows can only add one row?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows

I got a weird error and I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

I create a dynamic row within a ui form.
All this works as supposed. BUT, when i create a add a record i can only add one...
So the button works, no error but when i want to add another record it just doesn't add it. and there's no error whatsoever..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productaddons_options_form.options_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">productaddons_options_form.options_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option Form</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="options_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">FullStak\ProductAddons\Model\Options\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">options_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">productaddons_option_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="option">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option bundle information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="productaddons_option_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">option</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">option</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="comment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Comment</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">option</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="options_group">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customizable options</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <dynamicRows name="optiongroup">
            <settings>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Option</addButtonLabel>
                <dndConfig>
                    <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    <param name="draggableElementClass" xsi:type="string">_dragged</param>
                    <param name="tableClass" xsi:type="string">table.admin__dynamic-rows</param>
                </dndConfig>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="field" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label>Field</label>
                    </settings>
                </field>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Result:
[image: dynamicrow one rec]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and feel a bit stupid :) haha
It was a combination of things...

```
<item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
</item>
<!--<item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>-->
```

I had to remove the template item and needed to add layout->type: tabs.

And i had to have a main fieldset, with fieldsets within to make it all work together...
Hope i can help someone who also has this problem :)

Cheers!

Comment: great! could you post the full correct xml code?

Comment: Sure!
here it is:
https://gist.github.com/breakerh/4d10b18a5efbf601132a62080cfecacd

Comment: great job, it could be very useful.

Comment: Thanks hope i can save someone some time and a lot of headache haha :)